# Windows Form Application - TextBox c

Tags: c#, class, null

I was trying to verify if Text property from TextBox class contains something.
Like, we have an instance of TextBox, called "usernamePassword"
and I want to do something like that:

```
if(usernamePassword != null) {do something}
```

But, it doesn't work, like it contains something by default, but not null.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have to use  `if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(usernamePassword.Text))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the "Text" property of the Textbox control. It should be as follows.

```
if(usernamePassword.Text != String.Empty) {do something}
```